# Trying to convert time bins to mins and hours array in Pyspark with JSON structure

Tags: python, json, pyspark

My data is in the format

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td> id </td>
<td> field_2 </td>
<td> field_3 </td>
<td> date </td>
<td> a_blob </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> some_data </td>
<td> some_data </td>
<td> 11/1/2020 </td>
<td> {"name": "abc1", "usage_count": {"bin102": 1, "bin103": 1, "bin104": 1, "bin105": 1, "bin110": 1, "bin112": 1, "bin120": 1, "bin121": 1, "bin122": 1, "bin123": 1, "bin124": 1, "bin136": 2, "bin137": 1, "bin138": 1, "bin139": 1, "bin140": 1, "bin141": 2, "bin142": 2}, "usage_min": {"bin102": 7.7, "bin103": 10, "bin104": 10, "bin105": 2.5, "bin110": 0.1, "bin112": 0.8, "bin120": 6.8, "bin121": 10, "bin122": 10, "bin123": 10, "bin124": 4.3, "bin136": 2.5, "bin137": 10, "bin138": 10, "bin139": 10, "bin140": 10, "bin141": 9.3, "bin142": 3.8}, "p_name": "abc_1"}  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I want to convert it to the following format

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td> id </td>
<td> field_2 </td>
<td> field_3 </td>
<td> date </td>
<td>  mins_arr </td>
<td>   cnt_arr </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> some_data </td>
<td> some_data </td>
<td> 11/1/2020 </td>
<td> 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,24.9,50.0,9.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0</td>
<td> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm using the following code to do this conversion

```
def convert_to_dense_bins(u_count, u_minutes):
count = [0] * 144
minutes = [0.0] * 144
for key in u_count:
    bin_number = key.split("bin")[1]
    count[int(bin_number, 10)] = u_count[key]
    bin_minutes = u_minutes[key]
    minutes[int(bin_number, 10)] = bin_minutes
return count, minutes


def aggregate_to_hourly_bins(count_bin, minutes_bin):
    count = []
    minutes = []
    for i in range(0, 144, 6):
        hour_count = sum(count_bin[i:i + 6])
        count.append(str(hour_count))
        hour_minutes = sum(minutes_bin[i:i + 6])
        minutes.append(str(hour_minutes))
    return count, minutes


def transform(row):
    e_data = json.loads(row[4])
    p_name = e_data["p_name"]
    name = e_data["name"]
    count_bin, minutes_bin = convert_to_dense_bins(e_data["usage_count"],
                                                   e_data["usage_minutes"])
    count_hourly, minutes_hourly = aggregate_to_hourly_bins(count_bin, minutes_bin)
    return (row.id, name, row.feature_1, row.feature_2, p_name, row.date, ','.join(minutes_hourly),
            ','.join(count_hourly))

    new_columns = ["id", "name", "feature_1", "feature_2", "p_name", "date", "mins_arr", "cnt_arr"]
    df = df_old.rdd \
        .filter(some_filter_function) \
        .map(transform) \
        .toDF(new_columns)
```

This code is taking too long as my data grows. I'm looking for more efficient ways to do this transformation in PySpark. I'm not able to use windows functions and such due to the complexity of JSON structures inside data that are parsed as strings. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the question @jxc.
However, I'm trying to find a solution for Spark version 2.3.1. The above question answers it for spark versions 2.4+. Do you know what equivalent can I use in lower Spark versions?

Answer (score 0):

For Spark **2.3.1**, use [pandas_udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf), see below:

**Step-1:** use [json_tuple](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple) function to retrieve `usage_count` and `usage_min` as StringType fields:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

j1 = """{"name": "abc1", "usage_count": {"bin102": 1, "bin103": 1, "bin104": 1, "bin105": 1, "bin110": 1, "bin112": 1, "bin120": 1, "bin121": 1, "bin122": 1, "bin123": 1, "bin124": 1, "bin136": 2, "bin137": 1, "bin138": 1, "bin139": 1, "bin140": 1, "bin141": 2, "bin142": 2}, "usage_min": {"bin102": 7.7, "bin103": 10, "bin104": 10, "bin105": 2.5, "bin110": 0.1, "bin112": 0.8, "bin120": 6.8, "bin121": 10, "bin122": 10, "bin123": 10, "bin124": 4.3, "bin136": 2.5, "bin137": 10, "bin138": 10, "bin139": 10, "bin140": 10, "bin141": 9.3, "bin142": 3.8}, "p_name": "abc_1"}"""

df = spark.createDataFrame([(j1,)],['e_data'])

cols = ["name", "p_name", "usage_count", "usage_min"]

df1 = df.select(F.json_tuple("e_data", *cols).alias(*cols))
df1.printSchema()
#root
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- p_name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- usage_count: string (nullable = true)
# |-- usage_min: string (nullable = true)
```

**Note:** if you load your data using [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) with the following line, then the above `e_data` column should be the 5th element (`df['td'][4]`) of the column named `td` (type=`array<string>`):

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag="tr").load('/paths')
```

**Step-2:** set up pandas_udf where we use [pd.Series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to retrieve all bin-entries into list of tuples with two elements(corresponding to `index` and `value`), convert/map it into np.array and then fill in an 1-D array of 144 elements with these indices and values. next use [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to split the above 1-D array into chunks of *24* and do `np.sum(axis=1)`, return the result as an pd.Series with values being list of floats.

```
def _pandas_bin_sum(s,N):
  ret = []
  for x in map(np.array, s.str.findall(r'"bin(\d+)":([\d.]+)')):
    try:
      z = np.zeros(144)
      z[x[:,0].astype(np.int)] = x[:,1].astype(np.float)
      ret.append([ float(e) for e in np.sum(np.array_split(z,N),axis=1) ])
    except:
      ret.append(None)
  return pd.Series(ret)

pandas_bin_sum = F.pandas_udf(lambda x: _pandas_bin_sum(x,24), "array<float>")
```

**Step-3:** apply `pandas_udf` and use `F.concat_ws()` to transform two columns:

```
df1.withColumn('usage_count', F.concat_ws(',', pandas_bin_sum('usage_count').astype("array<int>"))) \
    .withColumn('usage_min', F.concat_ws(',', pandas_bin_sum('usage_min'))) \
    .show(1,100,vertical=True)
-RECORD 0----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 name        | abc1
 p_name      | abc_1
 usage_count | 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,5,0,3,7
 usage_min   | 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,30.2,0.9,0.0,41.1,0.0,12.5,43.1
only showing top 1 row
```

Comment: @Falconic, would you mind to feedback for any problems with my answer?